# Validate entire form except fields under a specific div with Semantic Validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, semantic-ui

I'm using Semantic form validation in a project, but I got an issue.

There is a big form with four dynamic fields with lots of rules that is cloned from a hidden template div.

Example:

```
<form class="big_form">
<div id="template">
    name: <input type="text" class="validate">
</div>
<button>More</button>
</form>
```

Now when click in More, a new field "Name" appears.
My problem is when I try to validate those fields, the validator see the template fields as empty (beacuse it's really empty) and don't procceed with the post.

There is a way to bypass the div "template" and validate only those divs below?
The validator code is like that:

```
$('.big_form')
.form({
name: {
  identifier: 'name',
  rules: [
    {
      type: 'length[14]',
      prompt: 'Please fill something'
  }
]
},
etc.
```

Thank you very much.
Regards,
Al

Answer (score 0):

Cited from the home page of Semantic form validation:

> A validation object includes a list of form elements, and rules to
>   validate each against. Fields are matched by either the id tag, name
>   tag, or the data-validate metadata matching the identifier provided in
>   the settings object.

So yes you should be able to validate the fields that you wanted to validate as long as you explicitly include them. I don't see why the nameless input field inside div#template is causing a problem as far as validation is concerned.

Comment: It's because when I create a new field, a new identifier and name are assigned to it (field_1, field_2, etc.).
And all classes NEEDs to be the same.

So I think the best solution is to deny the validation in the div#template. But I think I'm not doing it in the right way, since I'm having no right results.

BTW, thank you for your answer!

Comment: In that case just make sure the validation selector doesn't cover the newly created elements. **Add** different class names to elements that you want to validate and those that you don't.